# Java Regex Find All Between But Last Character Not Preceded Or Followed By

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: `"stuffhere{@ name="productViewer" vars="productId={{id}}"}morestuff"`

How can I find everything between the beginning `{` and last `}`.

```
Pattern.compile("\\{@(.*?)\\}" + from, Pattern.DOTALL); //Finds {@ name="productViewer" vars="productId={{id}
```

How can I verify that the ending `}` is not preceded or followed by another `}`? The string may also be surrounded by other characters.

Id like for the regex to only return:  `name="productViewer" vars="productId={{id}}"`

Comment: get rid of reluctant quantifier. Make is `.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\\{@(.*)(?<!\\})\\}
```

`(?<!..)` is a negative lookbehind that checks your condition *(not preceded by `}`)*

Note that closing curly brackets don't need to be escaped, you can write:

```
\\{@(.*)(?<!})}
```

Comment: Works. I had tried using lookaheads/behinds but I was positioning them wrong.

Comment: Holy jesus. Why those unnecessary look-arounds? `.*` being greedy will automatically consume everything will the last `}`.

Comment: Not sure why, but simply removing the reluctant quantifier didn't work for me... @RohitJain

Comment: @ryandlf How did you use it. Using `(\\{.*})` should give you content from first `{` to the last `}`.

Comment: Hmm...i'll play around with that and test it out with just removing the ?. Thanks for the suggestion. The regex above is working fine, but I agree, if I can simplify it. Even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ^[^{]*\\{@(.*?)\\}[^}]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
(?<=[{])[^{}]+
```

i have never used java, but regex is international isn't it :)

EDIT:

wait... regex has errors...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String s = "stuffhere{@ name=\"productViewer\" vars=\"productId={{id}}\"}morestuff";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{@\\s+(.*)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```